# Stop autopep8 from formatting merge conflicts

Tags: python, formatting, pep8, autopep8

I'll have a merge conflict like

```
<<<<<<<HEAD
    ("experimental", "use_sell_signal", False),
    ("experimental", "sell_profit_only", True),
    ("experimental", "ignore_roi_if_buy_signal", True),
=======
    ("experimental", "use_exit_signal", False),
    ("experimental", "exit_profit_only", True),
    ("experimental", "ignore_roi_if_enter_signal", True),
>>>>>>> 98f08047d(Strategy added short methods and changed names)
```

And when I save, autopep8 formats it to look like, and then the merge conflict isn't detected anymore

```
<< << << < HEAD
    ("experimental", "use_sell_signal", False),
    ("experimental", "sell_profit_only", True),
    ("experimental", "ignore_roi_if_buy_signal", True),
    == == == =
    ("experimental", "use_exit_signal", False),
    ("experimental", "exit_profit_only", True),
    ("experimental", "ignore_roi_if_enter_signal", True),
    >>>>>> > 98f08047d(Strategy added short methods and changed names)
```

---

This is obviously very annoying, how can I disable this without turning off format on save

Comment: You have three options: 1. Turn auto format off 2. Don't save files with merge conflicts or 3. Live with the annoyance. Personally I prefer to format files on manual request only. It gives less surprises.

Comment: @KlausD I think it happens with rebase